# Photographers for Q&A sessions

Tags: discussion

What's some photographers that you'd like to see us get for a Q&A?  You can list some super famous people, but the odds are much smaller.  If we can find some obviously very talented, but with a bit of a following online photographer - we've got a better than 0 chance of getting them for a Q&A.  For instance, [John Parminter](http://1x.com/artist/14617) obviously has some stuff to teach about landscape!

So, community, who are some photographers you would like to talk with?  (One photog per answer please.)

Comment: Is this happening anytime soon?

Comment: @Vikas - This is one of the things I'm going to try to spearhead for the new year.

Answer (score 5):

### Patrick Smith

I follow him religiously on flickr and his composition notes on flickr photos have been very helpful for me. I'd like to chew his ear off given a chance :).

Comment: Wow, this is amazing http://www.flickr.com/photos/patrick-smith-photography/5916495923/in/photostream

Comment: @rfusca: Wow, amazing indeed! Regarding photogs, as far as I am concerned, we can skip Ken Rockwell...that guy doesn't need any more publicity or ego-stroking.

Comment: Can you separate out into one photog per answer?

Comment: @rfusca, Ken Rockwell was a sarcastic comment. My nomination is Patrick Smith. Sorry if someone upvoted for Ken Rockwell.

Comment: I realize now, looking over more of his work - that I've seen him *a lot*.  He's quite well known.  He's a *great* nomination, but he  may be at the edge of realistic - we'll just have to see.

Answer (score 2):

### [John Parminter](http://1x.com/artist/14617)

I love his work, and he definitely has a depth of knowledge that would be invaluable to any aspiring photographer.

Comment: Can you separate out into one photog per answer?

Answer (score 2):

### [Ken Rockwell](http://www.kenrockwell.com)

No, really! He's popular, influential, and, well, problematic.

I would love to point-blank ask Ken why he doesn't separate out his serious (and often thoughtful and useful articles) from the attention-getting trolling comments (which he self-characterizes as being like The Onion). It's a shame, because a lot of his good stuff is actually really good, and I feel like I can't recommend it because of the rest. I'm sure he gets a lot of hits from the troll articles, and maybe it's all about that, but it also costs him in credibility.

Comment: I think this has already been [answered](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11038/4390) - that's his personality, and the _personal_ website reflects it. Unfortunately, in written text, it's harder to convey what's meant as humor than in real life. But it's been a while since I read Rockwell; do you have any certain "troll articles" in mind?

Answer (score 1):

### [Marc Adamus](http://www.marcadamus.com/)

His work is a bit saturated, but his composition and scene selection is fantastic. He is pretty famous though, so I'm not sure of our chances here.

Answer (score 0):

### [Jack Brauer](http://www.widerange.org/)

He does some truly amazing 4x5 large format landscapes in the US. Not particularly famous as far as I know, but his work is superb, so he might be more well known than I suspect.

Comment: I loved his work on 24

Comment: @dpollitt You're thinking of Kiefer Srutherland.

Answer (score 0):

### [Hougaard Malan](http://www.hougaardmalan.com/)

Does some truly amazing landscape and wildlife photography of South Africa. I found Hougaard's work through DeviantArt.com, and his is some of the best there, but I'm not sure he is particularly famous.